# Python and Ansible - codec error UTF-8 to ascii conversion

Tags: python, ubuntu, utf-8, ansible, ascii

Setup:

- Vagrant VM on Linux host
- Guest OS is Ubuntu Linux (bento/ubuntu-14.04 image)
- provisionser is **Ansible**
- Guest OS python version is 2.7.9

Following scenario:

- trying to change **lineinfile** using ansible module in **postgresql.conf** file
- I receive following error message: *msg: 'ascii' codec can't decode
  byte 0x in position : ordinal not in
  range(128)*

I fixed that issue setting up **PYTHONIOENCODING** environment variable with following line:

```
 export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8";
```

in Vagrantfile.

Even though that solves that issue somehow, I get that strange feeling that either I am wrong, or Python software developers are wrong or Ansible developers are mistaken or this is some kind of [Linus](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) / Ubuntu distro easter egg, that is comes up with exactly 2.7.9 Python distro to annoy sotware developer and make them **think** instead of **do**.

The serious question is: "What is the real solution to that issue?".

Comment: In your local terminal, enter `echo $LC_CTYPE`. Then, from that terminal, logon to the guest, and enter `echo $LC_CTYPE`. What are the results?

Comment: @AntonisChistofides All-in-one output provided by  
`$  locale`  
LANG=en_US.UTF-8  
LANGUAGE=en_US:  
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_ALL=<br/>

Comment: @AntonisChistofides All-in-one output provided by  
`$  locale`  
LANG=en_US.UTF-8  
LANGUAGE=en_US:  
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_ALL=

I hate to admit - it's the best format I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that the remote machine (i.e. your guest) does not have locale `en_US.UTF-8` generated. Locally you have `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`. When ansible starts running in the remote machine, it inherits the same thing (ssh does this, maybe also ansible, I'm not certain), so, remotely, ansible runs with `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` as well. If that locale does not exist, programs such as Python will fall back to the default locale, `C`, which only supports ASCII.

In order to avoid this problem, I make sure the locale is generated. I have a ["common"](https://github.com/aptiko-ansible/common) ansible module which is the first module listed for all my servers and performs some essential configuration that is common to all. The first thing that module does (and therefore the first thing done on any server) is this:

```
- name: Install locales
  locale_gen: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - en_US.UTF-8
    - en_DK.UTF-8
```

(The reason I also generate `en_DK.UTF-8` is not that I'm Danish [I'm not], but that I often use `LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8` because I like dates in ISO8601.)

Comment: That did not change a thiing. `vagrant@vagrant:~$ localedef --list-archive` has output `en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8` and 
`vagrant@vagrant:~$ localectl status` gives `System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
                  LANGUAGE=en_US:
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105 
`